# Elasticsearch official docker-compose example isn't working

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I tried to install Elasticsearch and Kibana through the docker-compose example from [official manual](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#_prepare_the_environment)
and container es01 got down with this thing in logs:

```
2023-03-11 16:26:52 Created elasticsearch keystore in /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.keystore
2023-03-11 16:26:53 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 43:     8 Killed                  ( elasticsearch-keystore create )
```

I have tried to create elasticsearch.keystore by myself like it was [described in manual](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-keystore-bind-mount), but then it crashes because es01 tries to set new bootstrap.password that is already set.
Anyway, I want to understand, why the example docker-compose.yml is not working in first place.
I have tried both 8.6.2 and 7.17 and have got the same result.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug? Try an older tag?

Comment: But how could Elasticsearch run in container in last versions? I'm searching for avoiding this bug.

Comment: please share your docker-compose file

Comment: Do you need compose file? On the same page you linked, did the Docker run (one node) commands work okay? The same container image is used, therefore compose would only be the problem, if you (or the docs) missed some step

Comment: Please share the `.env` and the `docker-compose.yml` file. I have it working on my side.

Comment: @Paulo, I used docker-compose.yml from [manual](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#_prepare_the_environment). 
My .env is here https://pastebin.com/D7cff1cE

Comment: Are you sure about the `ES_PORT` ? Why do you out the localhost ip adresse ?

Comment: @Paulo I just uncommented the line from example to block connections from other hosts to elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in MEM_LIMIT=32384032 .env parameter. It must be set in bytes and I set it in KB and didn't notice for a long time. 32 Mb is insufficient memory to start the binary.